# Will ajax requests going to be stopped if a browser requesting them closed?

Tags: ajax

I have an application where if a user presses a button, one ajax request is sent to a ColdFusion page in the background.  This one request may take up to 20 to 30 seconds because it has a lot of records to insert into the database, etc.  I was wondering if they close the browser or navigate to another page if the ColdFusion request will not continue in the background (ajax request was already sent).

It appears from testing that it will finish inserting records, etc. even if the browser window is closed.  I was wondering if that is always the case and if there is a time limit....for example if a request will take 2 minutes, after the browser is closed it will stop working after 1 minute, etc.?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Christina, the time limit depends on your server time-out setting. It applies both to ajax and standard calls. It is usually set in a number of seconds and will throw an exception or error if it has been reached.

Comment: While there is a timeout waiting for a response, that does not mean that the ColdFusion request will simply stop - or am I wrong?

Comment: it should stop yes.
I believe this page documents it: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/194/tn_19438.html

Comment: i just wanted to add that this time out has nothing to do with whether the browser has been kept open or not since the request has been made.